# Synchronization in C with system calls

Tags: c, synchronization, system-calls, locks

I am doing something a bit weird but i want it fully synchronized. So i thought of asking your help. I have the following:

```
printf("My name is:");
system("echo syntax_Error");
printf("I am 17 yrs old\n");
```

this is quite abstract instead of echo I am executing a software that gives me an output, so execution time is unpredictable, but the order is the same. I want a printf then system call then printf such that they would come aligned as such

> My name is syntax_Error I am 17 yrs
>   old\n

I tried this order without locks but it didn't work which is quite obvious, or if it did sometimes it is unpredictable. I am new to synchronization structures so I would like your input.

cheers!=)

Comment: Which OS will this run under?

Comment: C usually doesn't flush its output buffer until it sees a newline.  I'm not really sure what this has to do with synchronization/locks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're thinking about threading and mutual exclusion (synchronisation) in C then look at POSIX threads.  (man pthread).

As others have said to get your strings in the right order flush stdout.  If you're on an OS with 'echo' that supports -n (no newline) this does what you're after.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

printf("My name is:");
fflush(stdout);
system("/bin/echo -n syntax_Error");
printf("I am 17 yrs old\n");
fflush(stdout);

}

$ cc     main.c   -o main
$ ./main
My name is:syntax_ErrorI am 17 yrs old
```

Rather than just use  'system' also look at 'execve' etc.  'man execve'

Answer (score 2):

You may need to explicitly flush the output buffer with `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf` call. The `system` call spawns a new process which has its own buffering. Eventually this process terminates and flushes its buffer, but the parent process' buffer is totally unrelated.

It is worth noting that most libc implementations will flush automatically on every occurrence of a newline character, so an `fflush` call would be unnecessary if you had a newline character at the end of the first message.

Comment: Yes.  Potentially confusing is that it would have flushed on a `\n` if the first `printf` had one.

Comment: I was going to write that too, but I don't think that would prevent the second `printf` from walking on the output of the `system` call. This really needs to be tackled from a higher (design) angle.

Comment: @Ben: The C libraries flush all output on program exit, so the echo will have been flushed to stdout before the second printf.

Comment: @Zan:  The problem is the first `printf`, not the `echo`.  The execution of something called by `system` is synchronous -- the original questioner totally misunderstood what the problem was.

Comment: @Ben @T.E.D: I think I meant to make that other comment in reply to @T.E.D, not @Ben.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use sync objects, you'd have to find some way to make that `system` call use them too. That would probably mean writing another program rather than using `echo`. Kinda messy.

Probably a smarter way to handle it would be to either use all the same method for your console output (all `system` calls or all `printf`s), or to pick one of them to output to a log file instead of the console.

Comment: two system calls might also be unpredictable as one is faster than the other! doing files is costly so it will be my worst case scenario

Comment: @Syntax_Error - If you mean speed-wise, it isn't signficantly slower than writing to the screen. Faster in many cases.